# Can I change icon into an image or emoticon in flutter dashboard

Tags: flutter

I'm setting up a dashboard on flutter and want it to support image or an emoticon instead of icon.

I've tried changing IconData to imageIcon but it gives an error while defining in child widget.

```
Material MyItems (IconData icon,String heading, int color)

 Material( color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0), child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

                child: Icon(                     //Icon
                 icon,color:Colors.white,size: 30.0,   //icon
                ),
                ),
              )


StaggeredGridView.count( 
crossAxisCount: 2,
 crossAxisSpacing: 12.0, 
mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0,vertical: 8.0),
 children: [
 MyItems( Icons.adb,"Alone", 0xffed622b,), 
MyItems(Icons.group_work, "Amazing", 0xff26cb3c), MyItems(Icons.sentiment_dissatisfied, "Anger", 0xffff3266),
 MyItems(Icons.wc, "Anniversary", 0xff3399fe),
 MyItems(Icons.art_track, "Art", 0xff622F74),
 ]
```

I expect to change icon to image or emoticon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an Image then use `Image.asset` or `Image.network` named constructor.

```
Image.asset('path-to-asset');
Image.network('image-url');
```

For emoticon you can use `Text` widget and pass Unicode points for that emoji in `Text` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String emojiCode = '\u2764';
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Text(emojiCode));
  }
}
```